# Create list from each column of matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix `M` and I want to create 3 lists that each list contains row names of matrix `M` means that fro examle for the fisrt list, I want to have `m[, 1]$a = 1` and `m[ ,1]$b = 2`.  How can I do this in R for each column?

```
    m
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
  a    1    3    5
  b    2    4    6
```

I have tried this code, but it's not my desire result

```
  > list(m[, 1])
  [[1]]
   a b 
   1 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will create a list of lists:

```
apply(M, 2, as.list)
```

And if your matrix had colnames, those would even be used as the names of your top-level list:

```
M <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("a", "b"), c("c1", "c2", "c3")))
apply(M, 2, as.list)
# $c1
# $c1$a
# [1] 1
#
# $c1$b
# [1] 2
#
#
# $c2
# $c2$a
# [1] 3
#
# $c2$b
# [1] 4
#
#
# $c3
# $c3$a
# [1] 5
#
# $c3$b
# [1] 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but How can I have 3 seperate lits not all of them in one list?

Comment: What difference does it make? Assuming `Z <- apply(M, 2, as.list)` you can access the lists using `Z[[1]]`, `Z[[2]]`, `Z[[3]]`. Also `Z[["c1"]]`, `Z[["c2"]]`, `Z[["c3"]]` if your matrix had column names.

Comment: If `MM` is the result of the `apply` then `MM[,1]$a` gives an error so it would not seem to answer the stated question (which was to create a matrix/list such that that expression works).

Comment: ...which was my intent all along. Nobody in his right mind would use an object like that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command:

```
list.m <- as.list(m[,1])
```

Comment: this makes a list element out of each row not each column

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# input matrix
m <- matrix(1:6, 2, dimnames = list(c("a", "b"), NULL))

# convert it to a list constructed such that L[, 1]$a gives 1
L <- as.list(m)
dim(L) <- dim(m)
dimnames(L) <- dimnames(m)
```

Now we have:

```
> L[, 1]$a
[1] 1
```